# Remove Android Studio "Method invocation 'getFragment' may produce 'NullPointerException" warning?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, warnings

Android studio gives me warning `Method invocation 'getFragment' may produce 'NullPointerException'` on the following statement

```
toSwitch = ((LoginActivity) getActivity()).getFragment(LoginFragment.class.getName());
```

I have read other question relating to this they say to use assertion or `Objects.requireNonNull()` but this is not I want.

**Before Marking this as duplicate**

The method `getFragment(String name)` can return null value and it is a required behavior. How can I tell android studio that I need that null value and it is perfectly ok.

Comment: The warning you get says that the _method invocation_ may produce the NPE. That means, the result of `getActivity()` may be `null`. The warning tells you nothing about the result of `getFragment` (which is regardless nonetheless here).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose is right and an easy fix here is to replace `getActivity()` with `requireActivity()` that either returns a nonnull or throws an exception.

Comment: @laalto But the function can return the value and its perfectly ok

Comment: It's not about `getFragment()` but `getActivity()`.

Comment: @TrueCoder: "But the function can return the value and its perfectly ok" => If `getActivity()` returns `null`, then you will get a NPE. This is not ok! The method `getFragment` is irrelevant here.

Comment: @laalto Oh, I got it. It was a silly mistake. Thanks btw.